# LSTM model with parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm trying to make a LSTM model in Keras with the following parameters:

[image]

However, I'm not sure my code is right.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(3, 1))) #16 neurons (?)

model.add(LSTM(32))

model.add(LSTM(64))

model.add(Dense(units =128))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

Comment: Please elaborate your questions, use full forms, share the context, what you want to do, what all you have tried, and specifically what you need a second view on.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As per the your requirement below code can be used

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(16, return_sequences=True, activation='relu', input_shape=(3, 1))) #16 neurons (?)

model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))

model.add(LSTM(64))

model.add(Dense(units =128))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss='mse')

model.fit(x_train, epochs=300, batch_size=10)
```